# Why Using attribute fixed the element changes its size?

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have a table which has the same width but i need the header fixed so I use this attribute (fixed) at header but oh surprise! when I use this attribute the header changes it size and now is smaller than the other part of the table...It's like if it the table is now wrap content (like in android attribute) and If i delete the attribute:fixed line my header gets the same width of the rest of the table, How can I use fixed and without lose the originally width?

My hedaer

```
th{
    position: fixed;
 top: -90px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 color: #525552;
 text-align: center;
}
```

and my tds

```
td{
 border: 2px solid #525552;
 width: 164.7px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: could you do a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't!

A `position:fixed` element is not subject to any other element on the page, but to the viewport only:

[**MDN Definition**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport.

So, if you set the position to `fixed`, you can no longer inherit the parent's width (in this case, the table)